# Applying for US H4 visa when I have a valid B1 visa

Tags: usa

I have a valid B1 visa. My spouse is holding an H1 visa and I would like to go as a dependent [H4]. If I apply for an H4 now will it invalidate my B1 visa?

Comment: Flagged for migration.

Comment: I have no idea BUT read the fine print carefully. I recently read about a female journalist who had applied for a longer term US Visa but it was taking too long and they were transiting so applied for a shorter tewrm tourist visa. Arrived at US immigration were detained. Roughly interviewed and treated like scum, put in prison cell (posters on corridor wall telling how to report rape. Treated generally abominably then deported after two days Why? - Fine print said it was illegal to apply for tourist visa once you had applied for the other. US were within there rights to do stupid ....

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: One of my friend was also put in prison for similar 'crime' and then deported.

Comment: ... things even though it made no sense AND had the "because we can" right to treat them like criminals but they stupidly availed themselves of the right for no good reason. I think her partner was an accountant. I suspect that in her position I would have found the treatment laughable, and pathetic and the loss of time and future status annoying but not half as scary as she did (but I may be wrong)(and being an old male used to having interesting things happen helps) BUT if you do not want similar to happen take SUPER care with guys who can and do act rather too like ....

Comment: .... the people they fought 70+ years ago. Sadly.

Comment: @NeonGlow I had a friend who went from China to Hong Kong 'for the day' and somebody helpfully converted his multi entry visa into a new 1 shot one and he ended up in a locked room on the Chinese border for "some while". Not at all amused. || With your friend's experience and my account and others similar I imagine you will be reading all the fine print :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon : Scary stuff. I must be careful if I don't want to get punished for my ignorance. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not invalidate your tourist visa by applying for H4. While you wait for your H4, you should probably not travel to the US because people tell scary unbelievable stories which accidentally may be true in some extreme marginal cases, and you don't want them to happen to you. After all, people in the US who work as border control inspectors do that for a reason, which is mostly because it makes them feel powerful.